# USDZ partly working in web ar model viewer

Tags: augmented-reality, fbx, usdz, web-ar

I made a model in Blender with different objects combined. Some of the objects have animation. If I export the model in blender to an FBX it works in the xr model viewer.
When I export the FBX via an online converter to a USDZ the model does not work or without the objects with animations.

I use the Google model-viewer.

I tried to export the models without animations, I tried to export only the models with animations. This did not work.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to export a model to USDZ with animations?